# How to index a SQL table on a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have the schema below - Let's pretend that there are 2 countries, A and B.
Country A has 1000 teams whereas country B has 100,000,000 - If I want to quickly query results based off which country the team is in, how would I construct my index?

Teams cannot change country if that helps.

[image]

Comment: I think joining these tables in an Indexed view is what you need.

Comment: Construct your query FIRST. Then worry about performance. We can only assume you have done your homework and thoughtfully chosen the clustered index as well as added indexes to support your foreign keys. The 100million number seems more like a troll than reality - but seriously skewed data often requires a different approach to crafting efficient queries.

Comment: Please add the specific query you want to optimize. A situation like this one can greatly benefit from a filtered/partial index, but it's difficult to answer without looking at the specific query.

Comment: One thought - try two separate queries. Search for a team in Country A first, that has to be a simple query. The optimise the second query because you already know it is in Country B

Comment: I don't know what this means:  "If I want to quickly query results based off which country the team is in".  Does this mean you have two queries -- essentially -- and one returns all teams in A and the other all teams in B?

Comment: Usually good indexes on the individual tables is all you need. (Indexed View or Materialized View is an option, but not for such a simple structure as this) Please post the query syntax and the execution plan. From those we can help you identify any indexes that might be required, but don't create an index for the sake of it, base these decisions on facts, not assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing a table depend upon knowing real schema.

For this simple table schema, I will create only `Trusted FK` between tables, at least this will be my first try.

Assuming `Countryid`,`Teamid`,`Resultid` are  auto increment.

```
CREATE TABLE Country
(
    id          INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    CountryName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Team
(
    id        INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    TeamName  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    CountryID INT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Team WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Team_CountryID 
        FOREIGN KEY(CountryID) REFERENCES dbo.Country(id);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Team WITH CHECK 
    CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Team_CountryID;

--Just verify that newly created FK is trusted or not.
SELECT 
    name, 
    is_disabled, 
    is_not_trusted
FROM
    sys.foreign_keys
WHERE 
    name = 'FK_Team_CountryID';

CREATE TABLE Result
(
    id     INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    TeamId INT NOT NULL, 
    Result INT NOT NULL
);

-- I have no idea how you are storing Result,so ignore it

ALTER TABLE dbo.Result WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Result_TeamId 
        FOREIGN KEY(TeamId) REFERENCES dbo.Team(id);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Result WITH CHECK 
    CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Result_TeamId;
```

May be after seeing query plan of real query, I will `De-normalise` `Result` table to add `Countryid` , but for now it is not require since country table will be small